# Is there a way to prevent sourced scripts in POSIX sh from running anything in global scope?

Tags: linux, shell, scope, sh, posix

I'm making a thing which has to source
a POSIX shell script (**NOT BASH**) as its configuration
file, but it should only have definitions of variables,
functions and comments, nothing else like running something in
global scope, so I wonder, is there a way to
stop users from being able to run any code globally,
only in functions and stuff?

I mean:

- main.sh

```sh
# ...
# . in POSIX sh has the same meaning as "source" in bash
. /etc/something/config.sh
echo "$(get_hello), $ME"
# ...
```

- /etc/something/config.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# This one is fine
export ME='Some user'
hello='hi :)'

# This is fine too
get_hello() {
    echo '$hello'
}

# This should error or be ignored
echo 'I should not be executed/should throw an error'
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Why is this tagged bash if you explicitly don't want to target it?

Comment: @Shawn will change it ig, though bash is a posix complient shell so eh, but bash also has quirks which may not be universal in POSIX sh stuff, but okay, I'll remove the tag

Comment: What should `export FOO=$(touch somefile; echo foo)` do?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that is a seperate question, press "ask question" button, but this will create `somefile` (if it doesn't exist) or update its modification time to current time to current and then will echo `foo` and the value of `FOO` will be `foo`

Comment: I know what it actually does in a regular shell; I'm asking what you want it to do in your case.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It should keep the variable